# Sum of iid random variables is a markov chain?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose I have a sequence of iid random variable, $Z_i$ for $i=0,1,2,3...$ such that $$\Bbb P(Z_i=z)=
\begin{cases}
p, &\text{if  } z=1 \\
1-p, & \text{if  } z=0.
\end{cases}$$

Define $S_k=\sum^k_{i=0}Z_i$ and $\prod_n=\prod^k_{i=0}Z_i$ .

So I have to determine as an exercise in my textbook whether $X_n=S_n$ and $Y_n=\prod_n$ are markov chains.

What I tried to do is express $X_{n+1}$ in terms of $X_n$  and something only generated at time $n + 1$: $X_{n+1}=Z_{n+1}+ \sum^n_{i=0}Z_i$ from this I somehow can show that $X_n$ is markov? I'm not quite sure how to use $Z_i$'s probabilities. I'm stuck here, any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I solved this using the reasoning in the commments below and I would like to check whether my reasoning is correct:

1) So since $X_{n+1}= X_n +Z_{n+1}$ , it follows that $X_{n+1}$ is Markov since the $ n+1$-th value depends not on any of $X_0,...,X_{n-1}$ . It only depends on $X_n$ and a random variable $Z_{n+1}$ independent of  $X_0,...,X_{n-1}$.

This I kind of don't understand myself. Why is $X_{n+1}= X_n +Z_{n+1}$ independent of $X_0,...,X_{n-1}$ ? Isn't $X_n=X_{n-1} + Z_n$?(And if we iterate this to $X_1$ then we could say that $X_{n+1}$ is equal to $X_0 + Z_1 +...+Z_n+Z_{n+1}$ so this means that it does depend on those values?

For example what if I take that $Z_0,...,Z_n=(0,....,0)$  and hence $X_{n+1}$ would be equal to $0$ or $1$ but what if I choose $Z_0$ to be $1$ then the sum would be $1$ or $2$ ? So this means that it **is** dependent of $X_0...X_{n-1}$? Am I missing something here? Also, since the exercise gives probabilities with which $Z_i$ takes value $\{0,1\}$ , how are we supposed to use these?

2) It's markov for the same reason as 1)

I have the same doubts about the second one. What if $Z_0$ is equal to $0$? Then the whole product is equal $0$? And if $Z_0$ is 1 and all others are $1$ then it will be $1$ or $0$(depending on the $Z_{n+1}$-th value)? So this again is dependent of the preceeding values? Could someone please explain me if these answers are correct and explain why my reasoning is wrong, and maybe intuitively explain why these are Markov's. I would really like to understand this intuitively.

**Also, if possible, could someone please say whether** 3) $X_n= S_0+...+S_n$ and 4) $X_n= (S_n,S_0+...+S_n)$ are Markov.

I'm also interested in how could I prove these answers rigourously by definition which is if  $\Bbb P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1} | X_0=x_0,...,X_n=x_n)= \Bbb P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1} | X_n=x_n)$ then $X_{n+1}$ is Markov

I have asked [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444829/markov-chain-as-sum-of-iid-random-variables) question on CV but did not get any answers(even with bounty) I'd really like to understand it!

Comment: Notice that $Y_n$ stays in the state of being $1$ so long as we keep rolling a success with probability $p$. Once we roll a failure with probability $1-p$ the product $\prod Z_i$ will forever onwards be $0$

Comment: actually i dont understand why would it be 0? Could you explain?

Comment: Each variable $Z_i$ takes one of two values: $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$. However the product of any amount of numbers if one of those numbers is $0$ is... $0$. i.e $$a*b* \dots *0*c = 0$$

Comment: @okay, yes..that's trivial, sorry I see now!

Comment: @ThePoorJew "Why is +1=++1 independent of 0,...,−1 ?" it's not. nobody said it is. the definition of Markov is not "$X_{n+1}$ is independent of $X_0,\dots,X_{n-1}$"; rather, it's that "$X_{n+1}$ is independent of $X_0,\dots,X_{n-1}$ conditioned on $X_n$". That is, once you know the value of $X_n$, the values of $X_0,\dots,X_{n-1}$ don't affect the distribution of $X_{n+1}$. And this is indeed the case, since $X_{n+1} = X_n+Z_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is a bounded measurable real-valued function, then by the law of total probability,
$$
\mathbb E[f(S_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n] = \mathbb E[f(S_n+X_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n].
$$
Since $S_n$ is $\sigma(S_n)$-measurable and $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_n$, it follows that
$$
\mathbb E[f(S_n+X_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n] = \mathbb E[f(S_n+X_{n+1})\mid S_n],
$$
so that $\{S_n\}$ is a Markov chain.

Similarly, we have
$$
\mathbb E[f(Y_{n+1}) \mid\mathcal F_n] = \mathbb E[f(Y_nX_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n] = \mathbb E[f(Y_nX_{n+1})\mid Y_n],
$$
so that $\{Y_n\}$ is a Markov chain.

Answer (score 0):

Define $S_{n}:=\sum_{i=0}^{n}Z_{i}.$

Note that $Z_{n+1} \perp\!\!\!\perp 
\sigma(S_{1},S_{2},...,S_{n}),$
$$\begin{align}
    &\mathbf{P}(S_{n+1}=i_{_{n+1}}\mid S_1=i_{1},...,S_{n}=i_{n})\\ =&\mathbf{P}(S_{n}+Z_{_{n+1}}=i_{n+1}\mid S_1=i_{1},...,S_{n}=i_{n}) \\
=&\mathbf{P}(Z_{_{n+1}}=i_{n+1}-i_{n}\mid S_1=i_{1},...,S_{n}=i_{n})\\
=&\mathbf{P}(Z_{_{n+1}}=i_{n+1}-i_{n}).  \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Similarly，$$\mathbf{P}(S_{_{n+1}}=i_{n+1}\mid S_{n}=i_{n})=\mathbf{P}(Z_{_{n+1}}=i_{n+1}-i_{n}).\tag{2}$$

$(1)+(2)\Longrightarrow  \left\{ S_{n}\right\}$  is a Markov chain.